# multi accounting

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i want to make a php system that check for multiple users (multiaccounting). In one topic here i found a code which helped me a lot. It's about this one:

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d9211/2

I have one more question. I take the ips and the usernames from ip_log table and there one username have more than one row. So my question is, whit this sql how can i remove the multiple rows for every user and show only 1?

I mean my table is not like this:

```
('bob', '1.2.3.4'),
('tom', '1.2.3.4'),
('joe', '1.2.3.4'),
('sally', '2.3.4.5')
```

But it's like this

```
('bob', '1.2.3.4'),
('tom', '1.2.3.4'),
('joe', '1.2.3.4'),
('bob', '1.2.3.4'),
```

Comment: you want check if there are more then one username  or more then one ip?

Comment: No every time when one user log in in his account, he record one row in the database, so one user have more than one result. I need to check if there is 2 different users with same IP, but when i echo the result i get them for every row that they have in the table. Do you understand what i mean?

Comment: I have update my answer .. hope is what you are  looking for

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want aggregation?

```
select username, min(ip) as ip
from ip_log
group by username;
```